# Richfaces and Google Chart API

Tags: jsf-1.2, google-visualization

I am using Google Chart API 
it is working fine with JSF 1.2 and richfaces 3.3.1
but when i use  or  in the same page..
the chart API is not working (chart image is not coming)..
can you help me out ..
thanks in advance
...

Answer (score 1):

The following fixed the same problem for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Array.prototype.reduce = undefined;
</script>
```

source:
http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=501

Comment: The problems that may have applied to the Google Visualization API in 2011 in combination with other JS libraries are likely to be different now. In any event, the workaround of forcing Array.prototype.reduce to be undefined is bound to cause problems, and indeed, your code is very likely to fail now.  Please find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. finally I solved it , forgot to post the solution. I just made one simple html page with the Google Chart and Using Iframe from my main page (JSF pages) i imported those charts. it works. and simple to maintain also..